# Server Socket disconnects and stops listening

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, loops, client

This is a problem I never figured out. I've asked many people, and they don't even know. Anyways, lets get to the problem. Here's what I tried to do... Create a client and a server. The client connects to the server, and sends a message to it every 3 minutes (I reduced the time for testing). There has to be two independent threads however (one for the client and server). What I found was, the client would continue to send messages, but the server would no longer listen on port 1234.

Client:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.Socket;


public class Client {

        public Client(){
                startClient();
        }

        public void startClient(){
                new Thread(new Runnable(){
                        @Override
                        public synchronized void run(){
                                try{
                                        Socket sendChat = new Socket("localhost", 1234);
                                        PrintWriter writer = new      PrintWriter(sendChat.getOutputStream());

                                while(true){
                                        Thread.sleep(1000); // normally 180000

                                        writer.println("Hello Server!");
                                }
                                }catch(Exception err){
                                        err.printStackTrace();
                                }
                        }
                }).start();
        }

}
```

Server:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Date;


public class Server {

public Server(){
        startServer();
}

    public void startServer(){
            new Thread(new Runnable(){
                    @Override
                    public synchronized void run(){
                            try{
                                    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                                    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(1234);

                                    while(true){
                                            final Socket test = server.accept();
                                            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.getInputStream()));

                                            while(!test.isClosed()) {
                                                    Date date = new Date();

                                                    System.out.println("Server got message from client " + date);
                                            }
                                            reader.close();
                                    }
                            }catch(Exception err){
                                    err.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            }).start();
    }

}
```

Start:

```
public class Start {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new Server();
        new Client();   
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could tell me what is wrong, because I honestly have no clue.

Comment: So... *when* does the server stop listening? Are there any error messages?

Comment: @Emest There are no exceptions when ran. Here's exactly what happens. The server and client objects are created. The client sends a message, the server responds. The client sends another message, the server doesn't respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write below two lines out of `while` loop in Server class and it will work for you.

```
 final Socket test = server.accept();
 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(test.getInputStream()));
```

What is happening in your code : Server will wait for new client every time after completion of the while loop but there is no client which is going to connected with server at that instance. So server will wait untill a new client will come and server will accept that new client and continue its processing.

Comment: That's interesting. I didn't know it would do that. Thanks!

Comment: im having this same problem in C# will this same method work as well

Answer (score 0):

you are stack in a loop, try close the connection in the client after the message.

Answer (score 0):

See these links they use

```
socket.setKeepAlive(true);
```

[java.net.Socket TCP keep-alive usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810668/java-net-socket-tcp-keep-alive-usage)

and

[Permanent and persistent Socket connection in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29685705/permanent-and-persistent-socket-connection-in-java/29714530)