# java.net.Socket TCP keep-alive usage

Tags: java, sockets

How to use [`java.net.Socket` **`setKeepAlive(boolean b)`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive-boolean-) API?

I am hosting a simple server using `Socket`. 
The clients can connect and send data. I will not close the connection unless the client sends end of stream. The client can continue to hold a connection for any length of time. Data transfer will be going on, but suddenly I see that there is a connection loss without any logs whatsoever. Once the client is restarted (not server), the transmission begins again.
I am not setting any `timeout` as by default it is infinity. I want to understand what `setKeepAlive` actually does so that I will be able to decide whether I need to set that to `true`. 
Can someone help me understand the same? thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could clarify what exactly the problem is? And maybe post the code that causes you trouble.

Comment: If you don't understand what `setKeepAlive()` does, then how do you know that it solves your problem?

Comment: Hi , I edited my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the documentation for [`setKeepAlive()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setKeepAlive-boolean-) says, it will enable (or disable) the [`SO_KEEPALIVE`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/SocketOptions.html#SO_KEEPALIVE) option on the socket.

> When the keepalive option is set for a TCP socket and no data has been exchanged across the socket in either direction for 2 hours (NOTE: the actual value is implementation dependent), TCP automatically sends a keepalive probe to the peer. This probe is a TCP segment to which the peer must respond. One of three responses is expected: 1. The peer responds with the expected ACK. The application is not notified (since everything is OK). TCP will send another probe following another 2 hours of inactivity. 2. The peer responds with an RST, which tells the local TCP that the peer host has crashed and rebooted. The socket is closed. 3. There is no response from the peer. The socket is closed. The purpose of this option is to detect if the peer host crashes. Valid only for TCP socket: SocketImpl

[Here](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.7.shtml) is another reference explaining the `SO_KEEPALIVE` option.

---

Note that in networking, connections can be lost at any time for a myriad of reasons.  If the connection traverses a NAT router, the entry in the NAT table could expire (when the connection is idle) and the connection is lost due to that.  The client could cease to function, or be suspended (especially laptops and mobile devices), or a cable could be disconnected, or WiFi (or cellular) signal could be interfered with, or ... the list can go on.  Your server needs to be written to cope gracefully with loss of connection.

Comment: Hey thanks for your explanation. But how can I write code in my application to check whether the client is active, etc?

Comment: @LPD To check whether the client is active requires your application protocol to send a message and expect a response. In general, there is no way to know if the far end of a TCP connection is "active". The program may just have no need to send anything for a while, or it may have vanished (software quit, hardware died, power outage, backhoe broke network cables, and on).

Comment: It is not mandatory. You need to decide for your protocol whether or not it is suitable.

Comment: The documentation is incorrect. The socket is not closed. The application still has to close it. The *connection* is *reset,* and the next I/O operation on it will throw an `IOException`.

Answer (score 3):

I face the similar problem in my case

In JAVA Socket – TCP connections are managed on the OS level, 
java.net.Socket does not provide any in-built function to set timeouts for keepalive packet on a per-socket level. 
But we can enable keepalive option for java socket but it takes 2 hours 11 minutes (7200 sec) by default to process after a stale tcp connections.
This cause connection will be availabe for very long time before purge. 
So we found some solution to use Java Native Interface (JNI) that call native code(c++) to configure these options.

****Windows OS****

In windows operating system keepalive_time & keepalive_intvl can be configurable but tcp_keepalive_probes cannot be change.By default, when a TCP socket is initialized sets the keep-alive timeout to 2 hours and the keep-alive interval to 1 second. The default system-wide value of the keep-alive timeout is controllable through the KeepAliveTime registry setting which takes a value in milliseconds.

On Windows Vista and later, the number of keep-alive probes (data retransmissions) is set to 10 and cannot be changed.

On Windows Server 2003, Windows XP, and Windows 2000, the default setting for number of keep-alive probes is 5. The number of keep-alive probes is controllable.
For windows Winsock IOCTLs library is used to configure the tcp-keepalive parameters.

**int WSAIoctl(
  SocketFD,              // descriptor identifying a socket
  SIO_KEEPALIVE_VALS,       // dwIoControlCode
  (LPVOID) lpvInBuffer,      // pointer to tcp_keepalive struct 
  (DWORD) cbInBuffer,         // length of input buffer 
  NULL,                   // output buffer
  0,                  // size of output buffer
  (LPDWORD) lpcbBytesReturned, // number of bytes returned
  NULL,   // OVERLAPPED structure
  NULL  // completion routine
);**

**Linux OS**

Linux has built-in support for keepalive which is need to be enabling TCP/IP networking in order to use it. Programs must request keepalive control for their sockets using the setsockopt interface.

int setsockopt(int socket, int level, int optname,
                 const void *optval, socklen_t optlen)

Each client socket will be created using java.net.Socket. File descriptor ID for each socket will retrieve using java reflection.

Comment: Please don't keep posting the same answer in multiple old questions. Flag as duplicate if you think they are.