# When a BufferedReader is created from a socket, will readLine() == null if the connection fails?

Tags: java, sockets

This question is similar to [Sockets: BufferedReader readLine() blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139834/sockets-bufferedreader-readline-blocks), but not exactly.

If I have

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {....
```

and the connection for the socket fails, will I get a null read or will the bufferedReader just hang waiting for input?  I have my while loop contained in a try/catch/finally, and it never seems to get to the finally.

From my research, it seems that the only way to deal with this situation is to create a heartbeat process.  Is that correct?

Comment: If the connection fails, a subclass of IOException will be thrown.  The only way you can get null returned is if the socket closes, either because your program closed it, or because the other end closed it.

Comment: You will only get a null if the connection is closed properly by the peer. If the connection fails you may get nothing except an infinite block in `readLine()`. To detect a connect failure in TCP you need to have written to the connection. A read timeout may be what you're looking for. If you close the socket yourself you will get a `SocketException: Socket closed`. @VGR

Comment: Do you mean if the socket fails?  Is there any way to truly know if the connection between two sockets has failed without using a heartbeat mechanism?

Comment: I meant what I said. There is no such thing as 'socket fails'. Only connection failures.

Comment: RE:  user207421's comment, a socket can be "magically closed" by the SO_KEEPALIVE process (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31810668/java-net-socket-tcp-keep-alive-usage) or by the operating system.  The socket is closed by the SO_KEEPALIVE process "if the peer host crashes."

Comment: RE: VGR's comment, "If the connection fails, a subclass of IOException will be thrown." Is that exception thrown only when an attempt is made to write to the socket? Will that exception also be thrown when an attempt is made to read from the stream if the operating system "times out" the socket or the socket is closed by the SO_KEEPALIVE process?  Or as I suspect, does the bufferedReader just hang waiting for input?

Comment: Re @user2782's comment, a socket can NOT be 'magically closed' by keepalive. The connection is reset, but the socket remains open, and the application still has to close it.

Comment: Re @VGR's comment, read what I wrote above. You can get the `IOException on either read or write, but there has to have been a prior write, or a keepalive probe. Merely reading from a socket will never detect a connection failure.